# Can an NHiberate entity have a natural-id in a component?

Tags: c#, hibernate, orm

It seems impossible to me to have a natural-id in a component.

```
public class User
{
    private IAccount account;
    public User(string name, string password){
        account = new Account()
        {
                UserName = name,
                Password = password
        };
    }
}

public class Account : IAccount
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I want the natural-id to be User.Account.UserName. I tried proxying it, but

> Could not find field
>   'account.UserName' in class 'Customer'

which tells me this is not possible. But I may be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

Just look at the xsd: only a `class` can contain a `natural-id`.